# Optimize LINQ search with custom fixed ranking

Tags: c#, linq

I have to perform on some collection and return ranking based on some logic
I wish to optimize this working code since I think it can be bettered (maybe using tasks?).

I need to search on `Counterpart`s item. I load this data from DB and I've got more aliases per counterpart.

I need to return the result based on those criteria:

- `Counterpart` `Code` is equal to search string
- `Counterpart` `Code` starts with search string
- `Counterpart` `Code` contains search string
- `Counterpart` `Description` contains search string
- `Counterpart` `Alias` is equal to search string
- `Counterpart` `Alias` starts with search string
- `Counterpart` `Alias` contains search string

Each of those rules starts from Ranking 1 to 7 and I have to sort ok that ranking ascending.

```
public class Counterpart
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Code { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Alias> Aliases { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        Counterpart obj2 = obj as Counterpart;
        if (obj2 == null) return false;
        return Id == obj2.Id;
    }
}

public class Alias
{
    public int? Type { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }
}

internal class CounterPartRanking
{
    public int Rank { get; set; }

    public Counterpart CounterPart { get; set; }
}

public static class CounterpartExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<Counterpart> SearchWithRank(this IEnumerable<Counterpart> source, string pattern)
    {
        var items1 = source.Where(x => x.Code == pattern);
        var items2 = source.Where(x => x.Code.StartsWith(pattern));
        var items3 = source.Where(x => x.Code.Contains(pattern));
        var items4 = source.Where(x => x.Description.Contains(pattern));
        var items5 = source.Where(x => x.Aliases != null && x.Aliases.Any(y => y.Description == pattern));
        var items6 = source.Where(x => x.Aliases != null && x.Aliases.Any(y => y.Description.StartsWith(pattern)));
        var items7 = source.Where(x => x.Aliases != null && x.Aliases.Any(y => y.Description.Contains(pattern)));

        Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        var rankedItems = new List<CounterPartRanking>();


        if (items1.Any())
            rankedItems.AddRange(items1.Select(x => new CounterPartRanking { Rank = 1, CounterPart = x }));
        if (items2.Any())
            rankedItems.AddRange(items2.Select(x => new CounterPartRanking { Rank = 2, CounterPart = x }));
        if (items3.Any())
            rankedItems.AddRange(items3.Select(x => new CounterPartRanking { Rank = 3, CounterPart = x }));
        if (items4.Any())
            rankedItems.AddRange(items4.Select(x => new CounterPartRanking { Rank = 4, CounterPart = x }));
        if (items5.Any())
            rankedItems.AddRange(items5.Select(x => new CounterPartRanking { Rank = 5, CounterPart = x }));
        if (items6.Any())
            rankedItems.AddRange(items6.Select(x => new CounterPartRanking { Rank = 6, CounterPart = x }));
        if (items7.Any())
            rankedItems.AddRange(items7.Select(x => new CounterPartRanking { Rank = 7, CounterPart = x }));

        sw.Stop();

        Debug.WriteLine("Time elapsed {0} for {1}", sw.Elapsed, pattern);
        var items = rankedItems.OrderBy(x => x.Rank).Select(x => x.CounterPart);
        var distinct = items.Distinct();

        return distinct;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Distinct

Take a look at [the documentation for Distinct](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb348436(v=vs.100).aspx).

A couple things from the remarks should stand out for you:

> The Distinct(IEnumerable) method returns an unordered sequence that contains no duplicate values.

I know that the order of the sequence is preserved when using Distinct but that's an implementation detail - there's no gaurantee.

> The default equality comparer, Default, is used to compare values of the types that implement the IEquatable generic interface. To compare a custom data type, you must implement this interface and provide your own GetHashCode and Equals methods for the type.

Your custom type `Counterpart` does not do this. It should implement `IEquatable<Counterpart>` and additionally override *both* `GetHashCode` and `Equals`.

```
public class CounterPart : IEquatable<Counterpart>
{
    // ...
    public bool Equals(Counterpart other)
    {
        // left for you.
    } 

    public override bool Equals(object other)
    {
        return Equals(other as Counterpart);
    }

    public override bool GetHashCode()
    {
         // http://stackoverflow.com/a/263416/1402923
    }
}
```

Now you have a type that is safe for use with `Distinct`!

## AddRange

As far as I know, `AddRange` only throws when the collection is null. You don't need to check for items before you call it. That elminates a whole heap of code:

```
rankedItems.AddRange(items1.Select(x => new CounterPartRanking { Rank = 1, CounterPart = x }));
rankedItems.AddRange(items2.Select(x => new CounterPartRanking { Rank = 2, CounterPart = x }));
rankedItems.AddRange(items3.Select(x => new CounterPartRanking { Rank = 3, CounterPart = x }));
rankedItems.AddRange(items4.Select(x => new CounterPartRanking { Rank = 4, CounterPart = x }));
rankedItems.AddRange(items5.Select(x => new CounterPartRanking { Rank = 5, CounterPart = x }));
rankedItems.AddRange(items6.Select(x => new CounterPartRanking { Rank = 6, CounterPart = x }));
rankedItems.AddRange(items7.Select(x => new CounterPartRanking { Rank = 7, CounterPart = x }));
```

## Other comments

As I mentioned previously, this isn't gauranteed to be correct (but is in every instance I know of):

```
var items = rankedItems.OrderBy(x => x.Rank).Select(x => x.CounterPart);
var distinct = items.Distinct();
```